# Given only the minimal polynomial of a field and approx primitive element, find subfields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I want to solve the following problem.

*Given*: The minimal polynomial of a number field,
and a decimal approximation of the field's primitive element.

*Compute*: Is the number field an imaginary quadratic extension of a real field?

*More details*:
$K$
is a number field with a fixed embedding into $\mathbb{C}$, and you are given

1. the irreducible polynomial $m(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ such that $K\cong\mathbb{Q}(t)/m(t)$, and
2. a decimal approximation $z\in\mathbb{Q}[i]$
   of the root $s\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $m(t)$
   satisfying $K=\mathbb{Q}(s)$.
   Assume that $z$
   is a precise enough approximation so that it is closer to $s$
   than it is to any of the other roots of $m(t)$.

**How can I tell whether $K$
is of the form $F(\sqrt{-d})$,
where $F\subset\mathbb{R}$
and $d\in F^+$?**

We know that if $K$
has this form, then $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=[F(\sqrt{-d}):F][F:\mathbb{Q}]=2[F:\mathbb{Q}]$,
so one thing we know is that the degree of $m(t)$
must be even. That's about as far as I'm getting though! It has been too long since I've studied Galois theory.

*Example:*
$m(t)=t^4-2t^2+9$
and $z=1.41421+i$
corresponds to the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$.
I know that though because I did it backwards. I started with the field, then computed the minimal polynomial in a standard way, then I plugged that into a root-finder to get $z$
(which in this case is just approximating $\sqrt{2}+i$).
When I have to reverse this process, it's not so easy.

---

*Update - some progress toward a solution:*

I can show that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ if and only if $m(t)$ is of the form $t^4+2at^2+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Do this casewise depending on whether $d\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $d\in F\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Just form the primitive element and compute $m(t)$ in each case.

Comment: I am posting a similar but broader question on Mathoverflow, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234664/computing-algebraic-properties-of-trace-fields-as-given-by-snappy

Comment: When you say you want to know if $K$ can be written in the form $\mathbb Q(c,\sqrt{-d})$, you seem to have a typo when you specify $c,d\in\mathbb Q$. What do you actually mean?

Comment: @Mathmo123 woops, thanks! I'll fix that momentarily.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Okay there, I mean $c\in\mathbb{R},d\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Uh oh, I messed up again. What I really want is $K=F(\sqrt{-d})$ with $F\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $d\in F^+$. I have fixed it... it should be right now finally.